How to rerender a `View` for an `NSManagedObject` only when relevant fields change?
My app has an ItemGroupView which is rendered many more times than needed when I import a large dataset into the app. This causes hangs in my app. I know ItemGroupView, below, is the view that is rendered too frequently from using Instruments. Making itemGroup an @Observable might solve this problem, but I need to support iOS 16. The problem is that .onReceive(itemGroup.publisher(for: \.id)) is called any time an ItemGroup is save()ed, regardless of whether id changed.  I have such a large number of ItemGroupViews that rerendering them all is expensive even though each individual rerender is super cheap.
How can my view receive an event only when id has changed?
Attempt 1:
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ItemGroupView: View {
    var itemGroup: ItemGroup
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text("\(itemGroup.id!.uuidString)")
            .onReceive(itemGroup.publisher(for: \.id)) { _ in print("id \(itemGroup.id!.uuidString) changed")}
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default)
    private var itemGroups: FetchedResults<ItemGroup>
    
    @EnvironmentObject var persistenceController: PersistenceController
    
    @State var nextGroup = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Section("Groups") {
                    ForEach(itemGroups) { itemGroup in
                        ItemGroupView(itemGroup: itemGroup)
                    }
                }

                Section("Items") {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text("\(item.id!.uuidString)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                do {
                    if try viewContext.count(for: ItemGroup.fetchRequest()) == 0 {
                        for _ in 0..<2 {
                            let group = ItemGroup(context: viewContext)
                            group.id = UUID()
                            try? viewContext.save()
                        }
                    }
                } catch {                    
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                 ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItems) {
                        Label("Add Items", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItems() {
        let backgroundContext = persistenceController.container.newBackgroundContext()
        backgroundContext.perform {
            print("Add Items")
            var groups = try? backgroundContext.fetch(ItemGroup.fetchRequest())
        
            for _ in 0..<10 {
                let newItem = Item(context: backgroundContext)
                newItem.id = UUID()
                newItem.group = groups![nextGroup % groups!.count]
                nextGroup += 1
                try? backgroundContext.save()
            }
        }
    }
}

class PersistenceController: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCoreData")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

@main
struct TestCoreDataApp: App {
    @StateObject private var persistenceController = PersistenceController()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(persistenceController)
        }
    }
}

The app has CoreData model with 2 Entities: Item and ItemGroup. Both have a single UUID field called id. They have a 1 to many relationship. ItemGroup has a count derived fieldwith derivationitem.@count`.
Attempt 2:
struct ItemGroupView: View {
var itemGroup: ItemGroup
var body: some View {
let _ = Self._printChanges()
Text("(itemGroup.id!.uuidString) - (itemGroup.count)")
.onReceive(itemGroup.publisher(for: .pub)) { _ in print("pub (itemGroup.pub) (itemGroup.id!.uuidString) changed")}
}
}
extension ItemGroup {
override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
if key == "pub1" {
pub += 1
}
super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
}
}
In this attempt I augmented the app's CoreData model ItemGroup entity with 2 transient int64 fields named pub and pub.

Unrelated but do not name a custom object Data, it could interfere with Foundation Data.

OK thank you. The class is not named Data in my real code.

You could make a child view that only takes the properties as inputs that you care about changing.

I could do that but I think the problem is that I have lots of cheap CellViews which rerender when they don't need to. What you suggest won't solve that problem.

think my code essentially already moves the logic to a child view. Updated the example to show that. Please let me know if I misunderstood. Thank you

You could make a reducer that acts as go-between between an actual MyData and CellView. The reducer type would consist of only the relevant properties.

Don’t use ObservableObjects use Observable or  struct. If you switch the view will only redraw when something that it is using changes. Equatable for a View is never the right solution.

@matt I've googled for swiftui reducers but didn't find anything. Would you be able to point me to a resource? Thank you

@loremipsum I can't use Observable as I need to support ios16. Not sure you mean by using a struct - I think NSManagedObjects are classes. Thank you

If MyData is a CoreData object there is no way to tell. Observable objects only have 1 publisher for all variables

SwiftUI doesn't render anything but you can speed it up by making small View structs and only pass it what it needs not whole structs or objects.

First, try setting the @Published var less frequently, that way objectWillChange will be sent less often, and thus body called less often.
Then if you have multiple @Published vars and want to tighten up body invalidation, simply make a custom View that only has the attribute you want, body will only be called when the value of the attribute changes, e.g.
struct ParentView: View {

   @ObservedObject var object: MyObject

   var body: some View { // body called when any @Published property of object changed
       AttributeView(attribute: object.attribute)
   }
}

struct AttributeView: View {
   let attribute: String

   var body: some View { // body only called when attribute has changed
       Text(attribute)
   }
}

FYI SwiftUI doesn't render anything, it just diffs these View data structs after it detects a relevant change and uses the difference to init/update/deinit UIKit objects. So the smaller your structs, the faster it can diff. If there is no difference, then there is no need to update UIKit objects.

Thank you, but this does not help. The problem is that body is called far too many times, even though it's already very cheap.

Try setting the @Published var less frequently
